# Cannot find a package in Ubuntu 14.04 with apt-get install

Tags: apt, package-management

I tried everything but for some reasons I cannot find any packages in this new distro.
I wanted to install wicd, git, all of the packages cannot be found for some reasons.

I followed this guide and still don't find any packages:

[How to fix Ubuntu Package Repository Error](https://smyl.es/how-to-fix-ubuntudebian-apt-get-404-not-found-package-repository-errors-saucy-raring-quantal-oneiric-natty/)

And it still won't work.

Any ideas?

Because I am not allowed to post more than 2 links I replaced tt with **.
Terminal:

```
kev@kev-Lenovo-G580:~$ sudo apt-get update [sudo] password for kev: 
Ign h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease Ign
h**p://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                          Ign
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg          OK
h**p://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                        Ign
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release              OK
h**p://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                           
Fehl h**p://de.old-releases.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease               
Fehl h**p://de.old-releases.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease       
Fehl h**p://de.old-releases.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease     
Fehl h**p://de.old-releases.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg             
»de.old-releases.ubuntu.com« konnte nicht aufgelöst werden. Fehl
h**p://de.old-releases.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg  
»de.old-releases.ubuntu.com« konnte nicht aufgelöst werden. Fehl
h**p://de.old-releases.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg  
»de.old-releases.ubuntu.com« konnte nicht aufgelöst werden. OK  
h**p://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources  OK  
h**p://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages OK  
h**p://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages Ign
h**p://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-de_DE Ign
h**p://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-de Ign
h**p://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en Fehl
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources   404  Not
Found Fehl h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted
Sources   404  Not Found Fehl h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com
trusty-security/universe Sources   404  Not Found Fehl
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources  
404  Not Found Fehl h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com
trusty-security/main amd64 Packages   404  Not Found Fehl
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64
Packages   404  Not Found Fehl h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com
trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages   404  Not Found Fehl
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64
Packages   404  Not Found Fehl h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com
trusty-security/main i386 Packages   404  Not Found Fehl
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386
Packages   404  Not Found Fehl h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com
trusty-security/universe i386 Packages   404  Not Found Fehl
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386
Packages   404  Not Found Ign h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com
trusty-security/main Translation-de_DE Ign
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-de Ign
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en Ign
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse
Translation-de_DE Ign h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com
trusty-security/multiverse Translation-de Ign
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse
Translation-en Ign h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com
trusty-security/restricted Translation-de_DE Ign
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted
Translation-de Ign h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com
trusty-security/restricted Translation-en Ign
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe
Translation-de_DE Ign h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com
trusty-security/universe Translation-de Ign
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von
h**p://de.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von
h**p://de.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von
h**p://de.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease


W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/source/Sources
404  Not Found

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/source/Sources
404  Not Found

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/source/Sources
404  Not Found

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/source/Sources
404  Not Found

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von
h**p://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von
h**p://de.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg 
»de.old-releases.ubuntu.com« konnte nicht aufgelöst werden.

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von
h**p://de.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg
»de.old-releases.ubuntu.com« konnte nicht aufgelöst werden.

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von
h**p://de.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg
»de.old-releases.ubuntu.com« konnte nicht aufgelöst werden.

W: Einige Indexdateien konnten nicht heruntergeladen werden. Sie
wurden ignoriert oder alte an ihrer Stelle benutzt.
```

Comment: Did you do `sudo apt-get update`? What's the exact error you get?

Comment: Please post a screenshot or the text...

Comment: I posted the text when I enter sudo apt-get update

Comment: I'm not sure why you followed that link since it's only for old releases of Ubuntu... [Here](http://pastebin.com/hJ31fzBf)'s a good `sources.list` for 14.04.

Comment: I don't know why but I did `sudo apt-get install .` and then I did `sudo apt-get update` and fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you followed a guide which does not apply to you. Ubuntu packages for a given Ubuntu release are moved from `archive.ubuntu.com` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com` when that releases reaches end-of-life. Hence, if you wish to continue using an Ubuntu release after its end-of-life, you must modify your `sources.list` so that it obtains packages from `old-releases.ubuntu.com`. You are using Ubuntu Trusty (14.04), which will reach end-of-life in April 2019. Until then, its packages are kept on `archive.ubuntu.com`, and if you try to obtain them from `old-releases.ubuntu.com` you will get a 404 error.

So you should replace your `sources.list` with a clean one, for example [this one](http://pastebin.com/hJ31fzBf) (which is essentially the default one, but in a more condensed form) and post another question about your original problem (the one which prompted you to use that guide in the first place).